# MySQL server with root user that can be accessed remotely with just a password. How hard is it to break in?

Tags: mysql, security

I have a MySQL server that has a root user enabled. 
This root user is protected by a password and can be accessed remotely: `%`.

The reason for this is from time to time I use `MySQL Workbench` to access the server and run queries directly to see some stats.

I know that this is bad.

My question is how hard is it to break in.

The server has `fail2ban` installed so I think multiple failed attempts will block the intruder via IP. The password is somewhat strong.

As a follow up, what can I do to still be able to access the server with `MySQL Workbench` but improve security of the box.

Comment: You're better off using ssh to tunnel the MySQL traffic

Comment: @Phil absolutely right, if the reason only access from MySQL Workbench You can use ssh tunnel and setup root access for only localhost.

This possible as well and if You use MySQL under windows, just need setup ssh server (at least few good on market).

Answer (score 1):

create a user with certain privileges (depends on what queries you run). I also advice to disallow root remotely login.